# Can biztalk publish multiple xml (infopath) forms to the same document library?

Tags: sharepoint, biztalk

I have a need to do the following:

The business process involves several document types based on cXML.  BizTalk needs to be able to push these to a SharePoint form library (as InfoPath forms) to be manually workflowed.  Once workflowed, the xml doc will be returned to BizTalk.

In order to be able to use a single document library, I'll have to use content types.  Can the InfoPath connector work with content types in a single library?

BizTalk 2006, WSS 3.0

Appreciate any input.

dc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer [here](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/31620933/uploading-documents-to-a.aspx):

In the orchestration, add a Message Assign Shape
Add the following code to the Message Assign Shape:

SharePointOutMsg(WSS.ConfigPropertiesXml) =
PropertyName1>My Custom ContentType
[Add more custom metadata] ";

Answer (score 0):

If not using content types, the templates can be stored as items in a separate forms library.  BizTalk then associates the submitted document to the correct template using the href attribute.